# Why the biblography is not formatted?

Tags: bibliographies, urls

I have a problem with the bibliography. First position, I don't know why is goes off the page, and I have a right margin of 2 centimeters set. In the second position, under the title 'What is a botnet attack?' there are too large gaps between words, I don't know why either. Maybe someone will tell you where the problem is?

```
\bibitem{DDoS3} What is a botnet attack?, URL:
\textit{https://www.akamai.com/uk/en/resources/what-is-a-botnet.jsp/, [access: 22 january
2021]}
\bibitem{18} Input Validation Cheat Sheet,  URL:
\textit{https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/InputValidationCheatSheet.html, [access
15 november 2020]
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I've edited your question to remove the `biblatex` key since your code fragments suggests that you manually create your bibliography and you in fact don't use the `biblatex` package.

Comment: The URL in the first of the two bibitems you show currently overflows into the right margin since latex can't find a proper place for a linebreak. The second bibliography entry contains wide white spaces since the bibliography is justified.

Comment: In order to get proper line breaks inside of ursl, I suggest the `xurl` package, e.g. as shown in the following MWE, whith which you're hopefully more satisfied: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xurl}
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{DDoS3} What is a botnet attack?, URL: \url{https://www.akamai.com/uk/en/resources/what-is-a-botnet.jsp/}, [access: 22 january 2021]
\bibitem{18} Input Validation Cheat Sheet,  URL: \url{https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/InputValidationCheatSheet.html}, [access 15 november 2020]
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}`.

Comment: now the whole document has fallen apart for me, it shows me errors

Comment: @ph2021 - Please tell us more about the errors you're now getting.

Comment: \userpackage{xurl} not working, bibliography not change.

Comment: How old is your TeX distribution? The reason I ask is that the `xurl` package was launched about 2 years ago. Any chance you could upgrade/update your TeX distribution?

Comment: How I can do / I  use overleaf

Comment: @ph2021: [How can I switch between TeX Live versions?](https://de.overleaf.com/blog/new-feature-select-your-tex-live-compiler-version#How-Switch)

Comment: Please consider accepting the provided answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your TeX distribution is no more than about two years old, you could make use of the `xurl` package to allow line breaks at arbitrary points in a URL string.

If your TeX distribution is so old as to *not* include the `xurl` package, I can only recommend that you update and upgrade your TeX distribution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xurl}      % a generalization of the 'url' package
\def\UrlFont{\itshape} % use italic letters in formatted URL strings
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref} % optional
\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{DDoS3} What is a botnet attack?, URL:
\url{https://www.akamai.com/us/en/resources/what-is-a-botnet.jsp},
[last access: 6 June 2021]

\bibitem{18} Input Validation Cheat Sheet,  URL:
\url{https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet.html}, 
[last access: 6 June 2021]

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, that works, thank you